# How can i fetch uploaded images in web server and also delete the ones i don't want?

Tags: php

I am uploading images in the "images" folder on my web server and I want all uploaded images to be visible in a table in index.html page with a delete button for each uploaded image so that i can be able to delete any image i want to delete. I don't want anything to do with database and i will be the one uploading the images from my admin.
I only want a simple scripts that will do this job, thanks everyone

```
index.php

<form name="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>

     upload.php

<?php
$uploaddir = 'images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Image succesfully uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Image uploading failed.";
} 
?>
```

Comment: this not a homework platform.. You can have help if you have made an effort by yourself yet

Comment: Umm... you want us to write this "program"/script for you?

Comment: wishing you all the best; so, was there a question here? I fail to see one. What I take from this is that you want us to find scripts for you, and/or guess what it is that you have.

Comment: *"I don't want anything to do with database and I don't care about security too"* - Well, you should. Unless you're just dabbling with code just for kicks.

Comment: Hint : `unlink` is a function used to delete files

Comment: @uzair how can i use unlink? where should i place it?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, i have uploaded my code

Comment: @user8425573 have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have printed all the images which are in my **images** folder in a table with a **delete** button next to each image 
**filePrint.php**

```
<?php
    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    echo "<table>";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
         );
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo "<form method='post' action='deleteFile.php?img=".$image."'>";
            echo '<td><img width="100px" height="100px" src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" /></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE"/></td>';
            echo "</file>";
            echo '</tr>';
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I have put the action of form as `deleteFile.php?img=$image`
$image is printed using the for loop which gets all filenames with extension
I passed $image as query string and then received it on the other page and used the **unlink** function to delete the file
**deleteFile.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
        $imgsrc = $_GET['img'];
        if(file_exists($imgsrc))
        {
                unlink($imgsrc);
                echo "SUCCESSFULLY DELETED ".$imgsrc;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "PROBLEM IN INNER IF";
        }
    }
?>
```